# Как обозначить текущий пункт меню?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть сайт без cms на чистом html. Состоит из основных блоков  типа head, sidebar, content и footer. В сайдбаре есть меню. Если через редактор кода хрома поставить на  класс :active, то ссылка выделяется. Вопрос в том, как и чем (js или php или ...) выделить тот пункт меню, в котором сейчас находится пользователь? И если пользователь уходит на два-три уровня вглубь сайта, но раздел сайта тот же, то как быть?

Вот стили и меню (честно признаюсь, что взяты с гитхаба и немного подпилены):

```css
 #sidebar-button {
   color: #666 !important;
   line-height: 3em;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-left: 10%;
   width: 81%;
   margin-bottom: 3%;
   border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
   border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 }
 #sidebar-button:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   left: 50%;
   right: 50%;
   bottom: 0;
   background: #2098d1;
   height: 4px;
   -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
   transition-property: left, right;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
   transition-duration: 0.3s;
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   transition-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 #sidebar-button:hover:before,
 #sidebar-button:focus:before,
 #sidebar-button:active:before {
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">

  <ul style="width: 100%;padding-left: 0px; list-style: none;">
    <li><a id="sidebar-button" href="/1/page.html">Пункт 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="sidebar-button" href="/2/page1.html">Пункт 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="sidebar-button" href="/3/page2.html">Пункт 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="sidebar-button" href="/4/page3.html">Пункт 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="sidebar-button" href="/5/page4.html">Пункт 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Или может я тут совсем делов натворил и код в целом крив и безобразен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в стили

```
#sidebar-button.selected:before{left: 0; right: 0}
```

Либо отредактируйте строку

```
#sidebar-button:hover:before, #sidebar-button:focus:before, #sidebar-button:active:before {
left: 0;
right: 0; 
}
```

Добавив туда `#sidebar-button.selected:before` через запятую, как и остальное

Затем в html страничках в меню добавьте в меню `class="selected"` в соответствующих страницам пунктах меню. Должно получиться примерно так:

```
<li><a id="sidebar-button" class="selected" href="/3/page2.html">Пункт 3</a></li>
```

От себя добавлю, что этот код явно не для вас, и к тому же, он не валидный.
Лучше сами попробуйте изучить css и сделаете все легко сами и намного лучше.

Comment: Забыл уточнить, что файл sidebar.html вставляется(этакий include) в основной html. т.е. надо как-то автоматом делать пункт активным.. Если только несколько этих сайдбаров сделать и в каждом отмечать какой пункт активный, а какой нет и после этого подключать к основному html,  но это наверное не самое правильное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Очень плохой код, Вас разве не учили что **ID** должен быть **уникальным** и **ни в коем случае не повторяться в коде**

```
.sidebar ul {width: 100%;padding-left: 0px; list-style: none;}
.sidebar ul li a {...}
.sidebar ul li a:before {...}
.sidebar ul li a:hover:before,
.sidebar ul li a:focus:before,
.sidebar ul li.active a:before {...}

<div class="sidebar">
<ul>
<li><a href="/1/page.html">Пункт 1</a></li>
<li><a href="/1/page.html">Пункт 2</a></li>
<li class="active"><a>Пункт 3</a></li>
<li><a href="/1/page.html">Пункт 4</a></li>
<li><a href="/1/page.html">Пункт 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Лучше цеплять на li данный класс **active**

Comment: Если честно, то нет, не учили. В первый раз о таком услышал. Прочитал про это, действительно ID должен быть уникальным и не повторяться. Спасибо большое за замечание =) Есть вопрос - если я <a> буду ставить внутрь <li>, то получится, что кликабельным будет только текст в данном <li>. А как сделать так, чтобы весь <li> был кликабельным в таком случае?

Comment: Я рекомендую Вам задать этот вопрос преподавателю или почитать учебник по HTML и CSS.